# Django rest framework call doesn't work after a few hours but works upon refresh

Tags: reactjs, heroku, django-rest-framework

I hosted both a react app on Github and a Django rest framework API on Heroku. Everything is working well for the most part; however, when I make a call to the API for the first time in a few hours, the first call doesn't work but then works upon refreshing and continues to work for a few hours. Right now, here is how everything is set up:

Right now, my Heroku database is a Postgres free database plan; the GitHub is hosted with GitHub pages and makes calls to my API "projectname.herokuapp.com," and it works fine except for the first call after a few hours.

Because of this behavior, I thought it might be some local storage issue. Still, I don't believe this because the network panel shows a call, response code, and correct response data after the first faulty API call.

Here is one api call that doesn't work calling it for the first time in a few hours:

```
const fetchArticles = () => {
        var url = match.params.category ? `articles/?category=${match.params.category}&dash`:"articles/?category&dash"
        axiosInstance.get(url)
        .then((res) => {
            setArticles(res.data.reverse())
        })
    }
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you using a free dyno on Heroku? Free dynos go to sleep after a short period of inactivity. Waking up takes a bit of time. Are you sure the first request is _failing_, or is it just taking a bit longer than you expect?

Comment: I did not configure any dyno so I'm guessing it is a free one. I am pretty sure the request is failing because I have an alert that comes up that I programmed to appear when specific requests fail. However, in the network tab it doesn't give any error code it just says couldn't display response data.